# Quoting YAML (for Travis CI)

Tags: formatting, escaping, yaml, travis-ci, string-literals

How would I escape a whole line in YAML? I want to have `json='{"title": "travis_saulshanabrook_site","key": "'$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)'"}'`
 in a list, but I can't get it to parse into a string. I can put single quotes around the whole line, but then I would have to escape every single quote in my string, making it very hard to read. The string will be run as a bash command in [Travis CI](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most elegant solution is to use the [literal style](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2795688) `|` indicator, with the `-` modifier to strip the final newline. That way there are no extra quotes necessary.

If this scalar happens to be the only thing in a YAML file use:

```
|-
  json='{"title": "travis_saulshanabrook_site","key": "'$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)'"}'
```

if it is a mapping value for key `abc`:

```
abc: |-
  json='{"title": "travis_saulshanabrook_site","key": "'$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)'"}'
```

or if it is part of a list:

```
- |-
  json='{"title": "travis_saulshanabrook_site","key": "'$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)'"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a solution that makes escapes that string *and* makes it easy to read.

FYI this is what that string looks like escaped :

```
script: ! 'your_cmd json=''{"title": "travis_saulshanabrook_site","key": "''$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)''"}'''
```