# How to properly use curl in Travis-CI config file (YAML)?

Tags: curl, yaml, travis-ci

Ok. This is slowly driving me crazy.
I have set up CI on Travis for one of my projects. I'm running some JUnit tests and I would like to upload the tests results to my own server, so it's much easier to browse them.

Basically, all I want do is to call this:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Token someToken' -X POST http://my.server.com -F filedata=@file.txt
```

So this is what I'm trying to do in **.travis.yml** file.

```
after_script:
 - curl -H 'Authorization: Token someToken' -X POST http://my.server.com -F filedata=@file.txt
```

The problem is that for the line above I'm getting an error which looks like this:

```
$ {:"curl -H '\"Authorization"=>"Token someToken\"' -X POST http://my.server.com -F filedata=@file.txt"}
/home/travis/build.sh: line 45: Token someToken"' -X POST http://my.server.com -F filedata=@file.txt}: No such file or directory
```

I've learned that in YAML colon represents a pair of key-value and I've found out that one can just use the quotes to escape the colon.

Well - this is the place where I am stuck. I tried to apply those quotes in many different ways but somehow each time I keep getting the same error all over again.

For example:

```
curl -H '"Authorization: Token someToken"'
curl -H "\"Authorization: Token someToken\""
curl -H "'Authorization: Token someToken'"
curl -H '"Authorization": Token someToken'
```

I feel like being stupid and I know that the fix for this is probably a simple thing, but I've felt into that "escape quotes while escaping quotes" thing and if anyone could just point me in the right direction, I would be really grateful.

I'm also linking to those questions as I tried to follow them to solve my problem:

[Escaping colons in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873227/escaping-colons-in-yaml?lq=1)

[How to escape indicator characters (i.e. : or - ) in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301650/how-to-escape-indicator-characters-i-e-or-in-yaml?lq=1)

Comment: Can you do `- "curl -H 'Authorization: Token someToken' -X POST http://my.server.com -F filedata=@file.txt"`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting the same error. Also, in the Travis log file, it looks like the quotes are ignored.

Comment: Another, probably non-preferable, option is to use a shell script with that command (or generate it, if applicable) and run it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quoting YAML (for Travis CI)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572689/quoting-yaml-for-travis-ci)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok - I've managed to solve (or hack) this problem, by creating simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -H 'Authorization: Token someToken' -X POST http://my.server.com -F filedata=@file.txt
```

And then I proceed to call the script in .travis.yml file:

```
- ./upload_script.sh
```

All credits goes to @набиячлэвэлиь for suggesting me that solution in the comments.

Any other - nicer - solutions are more than welcome.

Answer (score 13):

In YAML, colons are delimiters that separate map keys and values.

What you have now:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: token someToken' "https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/tags/$TRAVIS_TAG"
```

​
is a map with key `curl -H 'Authorization` and value `token someToken' "https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/tags/$TRAVIS_TAG"`. You can see how this creeps into the build script.

What you want is a properly quoted string:

```
after_deploy:
  - "curl -H 'Authorization: token someToken' \"https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/tags/$TRAVIS_TAG\""
```

Comment: I see this was suggested earlier by набиячлэвэлиь. How did it fail?

Comment: I have following in my .tarvis file which works fine:`after_success:
 - echo somejson > buildset.json 
 - "curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --request POST --data @buildset.json \"https://hooks.website.com/catch/jhsgdjsag76t76\""
`
But when I use it like following, it fails.
`after_success:
 - echo somejson > buildset.json 
 - if [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" != "false" ] ; then "curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --request POST --data @buildset.json \"https://hooks.website.com/catch/jhsgdjsag76t76\"" ; fi`


Whats going wrong here? @banzaiman

Answer (score 0):

you can just change the syntax and get it running directly.

example slack webhook

```
 - 'curl args:  -X POST -H ''Content-type: application/json'' --data ''{"text":"Hello, World!"}'' https://hooks.slack.com/services/####/###############'
```